# jQuery modal is not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I having below code dialog box is open properly but I'm not able to see modal properly. I'd apply z-index to  box but its not affecting.
Please see the attached screenshot you will be get better idea of my issue. Please help Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#new_attachment_div" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
  $("#register").click(function(){
    $( "#new_attachment_div" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      draggable: false,
      resizable: false,
      position: 'center',
      height: 'auto',
      width: '60%',
      modal: true,
      title: "New Attachment Type",
      position: {
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: window
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="new_attachment_div">
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
  <p>Hellow</p>
</div>
```

[image: dialog]

Comment: Are you applying `position` attribute or not?

Comment: yes i'm applying it and its and absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you tried `z-index`, I have to ask how high of a number you used. You should use the browser inspector to determine the `z-index` of those social buttons, or their parents, and give the modal something bigger than that.

Another possible cause would be if your modal HTML isn't right at the root of the `<body>` tag like your example code, in which case you will likely have to either move it.

Comment: You'll have to determine what the social buttons use before knowing that is high enough. Maybe it needs `99999`, or `999999`. Some browsers have a maximum cap, but that doesn't stop some developers from using outrageously high numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `position: relative` to your dialog box. You need to have `position` attribute set to have z-index take its effect.

Comment: i will do it later

Comment: Why would he add `position:relative` to a modal? I think that what he's looking for is a z-index to 999 to not overlap with other elements, a position:relative won't fix that. Position its often absolute for a modal, not relative.